# Carrying forward a 'personal loss' due to itemized deductions

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, foreign-income

I have $0 AGI this year, after claiming the Foreign Earned Income 
Exclusion, and have repaid some student loan interest. The additional itemized deduction from the interest payment creates no benefit for me this year.

Is this a loss I can carryforward, or is there something else I can do to get tax benefit out of the interest I paid in 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interest paid that is not due to a business is not a "loss". No, it cannot be carried forward. It can only be used to reduce taxes in the year paid, and since you owe none, there is no tax benefit to be had.